# How to set up the ID of a json element in rdflib

Tags: python, rdf, json-ld, rdflib, linked-data

**Context**

I am loading a rdf file in [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and am trying to export it in json-ld.

The original rdf looks like:

```xml
<cim:Substation rdf:ID="_1234">
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>A substation</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
</cim:Substation>
```

The exported json-lib looks like:

```json
{
  "@id": "file:///path/to/original/xml#_418866779",
  "@type": "cim:Substation",
  "cim:IdentifiedObject.name": "A substation"
},
```

I cannot seem to override the `file:///path/to/original/xml` component in json.

**Code**

This is what I am doing:

```py
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph(
    # Giving an identifier or base does not seem to change anything
)
g.parse('path to rdf')
js = g.serialize(
    format="json-ld",
    encoding="utf-8",
    destination='path to json',
    sort_keys=True,  # repeatable output is Good.
    context={ some relevant entries (rdf, cim)  },
    auto_compact=True,
    # giving base does not seem to change anything
)
```

**Question**
How can I set/override the first component of the ID in the exported json-ld?

Comment: Based on the [RDFLib code for Graph.serialize](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/rdflib/graph.html#Graph.serialize), could you play with the `destination` parameter? Take a look at the part starting with `location = cast(str, destination)`.

Comment: Destination is unfortunately only where to write the result. I give there a PurePath.

Comment: Can you modify the RDF/XML and add `xml:base` to the root element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was in the `parse` method, with the parameter `publicID` which is decribed in the [source](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/main/rdflib/graph.py#L1416).

> the logical URI to use as the document base. If None
> specified the document location is used (at least in the case where
> there is a document location).

So my example in the question becomes

```py
g.parse('path to rdf', publicID="#")
```

and the rest stays as is.

Comment: can you please mark your own answer as the accepted answer? This will indicate the Question is solved.